# Django Admin panel displays object(like Category Object ) instead of using def __str__(self) function

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

Code from models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('True', 'True'),
        ('False', 'False'),
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True ,related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    image=models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='images/')
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    create_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

when add category in DB it shows as :
[image: Image of admin panel]

code from admin.py

```
# Register your models here.
from product.models import Category

admin.site.register(Category)
```

**I want to display category by their title not by model object**,

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation of `__str__` is wrong, it is a member of the `Category` class, so:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    # …
    
    #   ↓     ↓ member of the Category class
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer @Willem Van Onsem. It did work but as well my editor was indenting it wrong somehow, coz i was pressing tab. But, then i used spaces to indent and it works.

Comment: @raman4899: ah yes. Since Python is an indentation-sensitive language, it is better to work with spaces *or* with tabs, but not both interleaved.